# Inverse formula of "summing reciprocials of consecutive odd integers"

Tags: real-analysis, summation, inverse-function

I'm looking for **an explicit fomula for calculating the natural number $n$, as result value, from any (finite) given argument value** $$\text{Sum} \left[ \frac{1}{2 k + 1}; \{ k, 0, n \} \right].$$

Hopefully such a formula would be explicit and short enough to be entered and plotted through the Wolfram Alpha website interface; and ideally it provides some monotonous real-valued interpolation between successive integers $n$ and $(n + 1)$ for arbitrary positive real argument values $x$ with

$$\text{Sum}\left[ \frac{1}{2 k + 1} ; \{ k, 0, n \} \right] \lt x \lt \text {Sum} \left[ \frac{1}{2 k + 1} ; \{ k, 0, n + 1\} \right].$$

**Note (hint?):**

Web-searching for "summing receprocials of consecutive odd integers" I've come across a relation to the so-called ["Jeep problem"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22jeep+problem%22), and from [this treatment](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JeepProblem.html) I gather (and checked for small values $n$) that the explicit formula

$$\frac{\text{EulerGamma}}{2} + \text{Log}[ \, 2 \, ] + \frac{\text{PolyGamma}[ \, n + 0.5 \, ]}{2} \tag{*}$$

is suitable for calculating the result value $\text{Sum} \left[ \frac{1}{2 k + 1} ; \{ k, 0, n \} \right]$ from natural arguments $n$.

(I'm not even sure whether that's correct for arbitrary large arguments $n$; so I'd appreciate a proof of that, or any counter-example, too.)

If so, my main question, again, is for some (hopefully not too complicated) **expression of the inverse of formula** $(*)$.

Comment: I just realized: What I'm looking for is essentially the inverse function of the $\text{PolyGamma}$ function $\psi_0$. I'll need to research this further; and I'll let this question stand until further notice, for commenting.

Comment: The value of this sum is $H_{2n+1}-\frac12 H_{n}$ where $H_n$ is the nth harmonic number. This can be approximated by $\log(2n+1)-\frac12\log n+\gamma/2+\epsilon_n$ where $|\epsilon_n|<\frac{1}{2n^2}.$ It is going to. e difficult process to get a closed form for the inverse of that, I think.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks for your comment (perhaps it wasn't perfectly formatted?) -- please don't hesitate to expand it into an answer. Since eventually I'm interested in generating certain plots by means of Wolfram Alpha, I'd be likewise interested in any reasonably approximate expression for $n$, incl. an estimate of the "degree of approximation" as function of the argument value.

Comment: $H_z=\psi^{(0)}(z+1)+\gamma$ is the analytic extension of the harmonic number function $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ where $\psi^{(0)}(z)=\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). Also, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2 k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\, H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\log (2)$.

Comment: See [WolframAlpha Evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5B%7Bn%2CFindRoot%5B1%2F2+HarmonicNumber%5B1%2F2%2Bx%5D%2BLog%5B2%5D%3D%3Dn%2C%7Bx%2C+0%7D%5D%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D) for solutions to your problem.

Comment: Those square brackets in the question would usually be interpreted as "integer part", which in this case is zero, so you're just adding a bunch of zeros, and so the sum is zero. Better to use round brackets here, or no brackets at all.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: _"Those square brackets in the question would usually be interpreted as **"integer part"**"_ -- I've edited my question in an attempt to show unambigously that the square brackets are appearing there for enclosing arguments to a function; corresponding to the notation used with _Mathematica_. _"Better to use round brackets here"_ -- Certainly not, since I (try to) use round brackets exclusively for grouping of terms. _"or no brackets at all."_ -- Certainly not, since this could introduce ambiguities (especially with multiplication of terms).

Comment: People aren't Mathematica. I would have no idea what was meant by $$\text{Sum} \left[ \frac{1}{2 k + 1}; \{ k, 0, n \} \right].$$ Whereas I have no trouble at all with Claude's $$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2 k+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2 k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\, H_{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\log (2)$$ If $n$ is large
$$S_n=\left(\log(2)+\frac \gamma 2\right)+\frac 12\log(n)+\frac{1}{2
   n}-\frac{11}{48 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Ignoring the last term
$$S_n=\left(\log(2)+\frac \gamma 2\right)+\frac 12\log(n)+\frac{1}{2 n}$$ leads to
$$n=-\frac{1}{W\left(-4\, e^{\gamma -2 S_n}\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

This is a quite good approximation; for $n=5$, it will return $n=4.8975$. So, use
$$\large\color{blue}{n=\left\lceil  -\frac{1}{W\left(-4\, e^{\gamma -2 S_n}\right)} \right \rceil}$$

**Edit**

If you want an approximation (before rounding), let
$$k=4e^{\gamma} \qquad  \qquad t=k\,e^{-2S_n}$$ Using series
$$n=\frac 1 t- \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m\,t^m$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{9}{8},\frac{32}{15},\frac{
   625}{144},\frac{324}{35},\frac{117649}{5760},\frac{131072}{283
   5},\frac{4782969}{44800}\right\}$$

The numerators and denominator form respectively sequences $A264234$ and $A264235$ in $OEIS$.

Transforming the summation into a Padé approximant

$$n=\frac 1 t -\frac{665 t^2-2226 t+1020}{1353 t^2-2736 t+1020}$$ whose error is $\sim \frac{11 }{100}t^5$.